# Why the pandas read_csv action does not respect the dtype option by columns?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, dtype

I have the following csv file"

```
CBUSH_ID,Diameter
1104,0.25
1105,0.25
```

When I import it in a Pandas dataframe using column specific types, it does not work well to me.

```
Fastener_Data = pd.read_csv(filename, dtype={'CBUSH_ID': np.int32,'Diameter': np.float32 })

Fastener_Data
Out[222]: 
   CBUSH_ID  Diameter
0      1104      0.25
1      1105      0.25

type(Fastener_Data.loc[0, 'CBUSH_ID'])
Out[223]: numpy.float32
```

It reads 'CBUSH_ID' as float32 numbers instead of integer as specified in the dtype dictionary.
Does anyone know why?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe there is a number in that colon which is not an int?

Comment: CBUSH_ID column only has integer values, as shown in the csv file

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with your example data.

Comment: copying your file and code my output of type is `<class 'numpy.int32'>`

Comment: Why do I get a float format number when I print the first value (1104)? Fastener_Data.loc[0, 'CBUSH_ID']
Out[225]: 1104.0

Comment: @bernie, sorry I'm new here, what else do you need to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @manu: all I am saying is that I'm not seeing the error you're seeing when using your example data. There is something missing here, I believe. For example, are you using more data than what you have shown here?

Comment: No, I'm not. it is strange because the data type is correct when I call the first number in a different way, please see below. type(Fastener_Data.loc[0,'CBUSH_ID'])
Out[231]: numpy.float32

type(Fastener_Data.loc[:,'CBUSH_ID'][0])
Out[232]: numpy.int32

Comment: it also seems to be ok when I type         Fastener_Data.dtypes
Out[235]: 
CBUSH_ID      int32
Diameter    float32
dtype: object

Comment: When I do: `type(Fastener_Data.loc[0,'CBUSH_ID'])` I get `<class 'numpy.int32'>`.